# Syncing any local folders to OneDrive using mklink command

Tags: sync, symbolic-link, onedrive

I have come across a solution to sync any local folder to OneDrive by following the instructions in the link below: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/92892-sync-any-folder-onedrive-windows-10-a.html

[image]

**QUESTION: Will any change made on the files in the original directory (F:\Example file) be automatically updated on the files in the OneDrive Folder**

Basically, I am asking if the files in the original directory are actually "synced" to OneDrive as I make any edits on them.

I am asking because I am not sure how the mklink command works. I understand there are other parameters for the mklink command. So if "mklink /j" does not work, which parameter should I use to achieve my goal.

---

Comment: Does this answer your question? [File sync service supporting symbolic links](https://superuser.com/questions/989379/file-sync-service-supporting-symbolic-links)

Answer (score 3):

While Synchronization of OneDrive-external folders, by putting symlinks or junctions to such folders into the OneDrive folder, may have worked in the past, it doesn't (always) work anymore now. See also what [Microsoft says](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/can-t-synchronize-onedrive-files-and-folders-from-a-local-file-location-other-than-the-default-onedrive-path-b7eef9d4-4203-431d-8345-fe49254f9da0#:%7E:text=You%20cannot%20use%20this%20workaround%20in%20reverse.%20The%20original%20or%C2%A0%3CTarget%3E%C2%A0folder%20must%20be%20located%20in%20the%20OneDrive%20directory) about it.

Comment: We use this (mklink) on some PCs in our team and some of those files in the linked folder do not sync (they are not uploaded to OneDrive). We are still troubleshooting it, but it seems you are right, they don't sync properly. Will post more as we find out.

Comment: Thanks for your info. I have the same situation. Some folder junctions in the OneDrive folder are synced without problem. For example, I synchronize my "Portable Programs" folder with some 50GB this way, which is even located on a different partition than the OneDrive folder. OTOH, I'm not successful in synchronizing my "Work Documents" folder of similar size, which resides on the same partition as the OneDrive folder, neither via Junction nor via Symlink. I haven't yet figured out what the problem is. It's not due to extremely long file paths, that I have already tested and ruled out.

Comment: What I haven't checked yet are the numerous folder-internal file-junctions contained in my "Work Documents" folder. Maybe that's the reason why OneDrive doesn't work with that folder.